# Possible values of hyperbolic quadratic forms

Tags: nt.number-theory, hyperbolic-geometry, quadratic-forms

$\newcommand\Z{\mathbf{Z}}$Given an integral quadratic form $q$ of signature $(n-1,1)$ and a value $\lambda \in \Z$ is there an algorithm that can determine whether there exist $x\in \Z^n$ such that $q(x) = \lambda$? If yes, are there known implementations?

I know that representation of values by quadratic form is a difficult subject with a long story, but here the quadratic form and scalars are given, so this is a very restricted form of this problem.

If someone is interested as to why I ask this, it is because I implemented Vinberg's algorithm for finding fundamental Coxeter domain of such a form and I am looking at ways to restrict the possible values of the root norms. If $G$ is the corresponding symmetric matrix of a quadratic form $h$ of signature $(n,1)$ and $v$ is a root of $h$ of norm $k$ then we have $h(v) = k$ and $(2/k) Gv \in \Z^n$. This integrality condition can be rephrased into the original problem of the question. If we an exclude some norm values beforehand, that would be a big gain as the search for roots is very expensive.

PS: See [polyhedral/vinberg](https://github.com/MathieuDutSik/polyhedral_common/tree/master/src_vinberg) for the source code of this Vinberg algorithm. All comments welcomed.

Comment: The paper *Li, Han; Margulis, Gregory A. New bounds in reduction theory of indefinite ternary integral quadratic forms. Adv. Math. 327 (2018), 410–424.* [DOI link](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.aim.2017.06.033) might contain relevant material, as well as *Li, Han; Margulis, Gregory A. Effective estimates on integral quadratic forms: Masser's conjecture, generators of orthogonal groups, and bounds in reduction theory. Geom. Funct. Anal. 26 (2016), no. 3, 874–908* ([DOI link](https://doi.org/10.1007/s00039-016-0379-2), unfortunately now behind expensive paywall)